# Angular 5 asp.net mvc - Id number keeps increasing even after deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

im working with angular 5(VS CODE) on the front and asp.net mvc/entity framework(VS2017) on the back.
My CRUD methods are working,
but when i delete a row from the database and create a new one, the ID keeps on going up, meaning that if i deleted a row with id "2", and create a new row, instead of getting the number "2" for the new row, it gets number "3" - but in my database row number 2 was really deleted, so it looks like angular somehow increasing the id?

Park.ts:

```
export class Park {

    Id: any;
    ParkStartDate: string; 
    ParkEndDate: string; 
    ParkCityID: number; 
    ParkStreetID: number;

    constructor(Id: number, ParkStartDate: any, ParkEndDate: any, ParkCityID: number, ParkStreetID: number){
      this.Id = Id;
      this.ParkStartDate = ParkStartDate;
      this.ParkEndDate = ParkEndDate;
      this.ParkCityID = ParkCityID;
      this.ParkStreetID = ParkStreetID;
    }



  }
```

Angular calls to service method:

```
  deleteParkingById(park: Park) {
    if (park) {
      this.parkingService.deleteParkingById(park.Id).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.getAllParkings();
          this.router.navigate(['/park']);
          console.log('done');
        }

      );
    }
  }
```

Angular service method:

```
  deleteParkingById(Id: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.delete(this.apiUrl + Id)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

C# method:

```
 [HttpDelete]
        public void DeleteParking(int Id)
        {
          // var parkingInDb = _context.Park.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == Id);
            var parkingInDb = _context.Park.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Id);
            if (parkingInDb == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
        //      _context.Park.Attach(parkingInDb);
           //   _context.Park.Remove(parkingInDb);

             _context.Entry(parkingInDb).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

example of xml file of GET method (get all parkings):

```
<ArrayOfPark xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/AmitProj">
<Park>
<Id>31</Id>
<ParkCityID>1</ParkCityID>
<ParkEndDate/>
<ParkStartDate/>
<ParkStreetID>2</ParkStreetID>
</Park>
</ArrayOfPark>
```

As you can see, there is only one object, and it's id is 31 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the database configuration. Check in the database design of the table and the configuration of the Id field. It's set as auto-increment. That's why it's increasing nonetheless you delete an item. There is nothing to do in the angular level. The database is solely responsible for it.

Comment: But i want the database to control the ID instead of manually increasing it whenever a user enters a new row. There isn't a way to do it?

Comment: well, auto-increment feature of database works like this. If you want to override that, you need to set the value of Id manually while saving a record. @AaYy